# Remove duplicates from csv (ie remove original and the duplicate)

Tags: perl, csv, sorting, unix, unique

Scenario: I have two csv files. One CSV is a trusted address file (trusted.csv), the other csv is testing address file (testing.csv) that will have duplicates addresses from the first file.

The problem: trusted.csv has already been used to print labels. I need to use testing.csv to generate more labels but I can't have any duplicates. I tried merging the two csv files, but I cant figure out how to remove both the duplicate entry and the offending originating entry. Another problem is that I need to ignore case. sort -uf works like it should, but of course that means it leave the original value.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add what you have tried so far.?

Comment: ... along with some sample data and related expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are talking about `sort`, I believe a solution based on command line is OK.

This is quite heavy solution: I believe there is something better but for the moment I have no better idea.

You need to lines that doesn't match some other lines (or remove those that do match). `grep -v` does that very well and if added `-i` option, it doesn't care about the case. As you may have many duplicate lines to remove `-f` will be your friend as it allows to specify many patterns in a file. As many *nix commands and file options specifying `-` (a single dash) as a filename makes the command read the data from the standard input rather than from a file on a storage. To summarize : `grep -i -f - -v ~/tmp/file` will read the file `/tmp/file` and the patterns from the standard input. It will keep all lines that doesn't match the patterns and the match will be done regardless of characters case.

Now you need to build the pattern list which is the list of duplicate lines. `uniq` identifies duplicate **adjacent** lines, `-d` makes it print duplicates once and `-i` makes it ignore the case. to make line adjacent, you can use `sort` which with option `-f` also ignores the case. So `sort -f ~/tmp/file | uniq -d -i` get a file prints duplicates once.

Putting both parts together results in the following command : `sort -f ~/tmp/file | uniq -d -i | grep -i -f - -v ~/tmp/file`. `sort` groups same lines together so that `uniq` can keep those that are duplicated which are used as patterns to select lines that will be removed.

Let's take an example. The file below has one letter per line (`dup` simply identifies lines that are duplicated):

```
  a              dup
  b
  c              dup
  a              dup
  d
  C              dup
  e
  f
  c              dup
  A              dup
```

The application of our pipe of filters results in:

```
sort -f ~/tmp/file   |   uniq -d -i   |   grep -i -f - -v ~/tmp/file
         a
         a
         A                                         b
         b                    a                    d
         c        ----->      b     ---->          e
         c                                         f
         C
         d
         e
         f
```